# poems/phrases/quotes/stories/allegories about “good news”

Tags: word-requests

Looking for any poems/phrases/quotes/stories/allegories about “good news.”

The only things I can think of at the moment are: *报喜不报忧* and maybe *好事不出门，坏事传千里*.

Comment: @AMACB I'm looking for phrases talking about it, not just single words.

Comment: In classical Chinese, there's not really a single word for "good news", so it would help to know what kind of stories you're looking for. Good news in a personal sense? Political? Religious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three subtle poems by three grand masters.

李白  Li Bai

春日醉起言志

[维基文库，自由的图书馆](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh/%E6%98%A5%E6%97%A5%E9%86%89%E8%B5%B7%E8%A8%80%E5%BF%97)

```
处世若大梦，胡为劳其生。
所以终日醉，颓然卧前楹。
觉来盼庭前，一鸟花间鸣。
借问此何时，春风语流莺。
感之欲叹息，对酒还自倾。
浩歌待明月，曲尽已忘情。
```

春日醉起言志

維基文庫，自由的圖書館

```
處世若大夢，胡爲勞其生。
所以終日醉，頹然臥前楹。
覺來盼庭前，一鳥花間鳴。
借問此何時，春風語流鶯。
感之欲歎息，對酒還自傾。
浩歌待明月，曲盡已忘情。
```

In that poem, the wise man discourses on the Virtues of the forgetfulness.

After waking up from a sound sleep, he heard the singing of a warbler without knowing which day it was. The **good news** come when someone told him that it was already Spring, what made the happy man sing, having the Moon and the wine for companion. In the end, he returns to the "accomplished" taoist state, where being transcends emotions, and "all is forgotten".

---

杜甫  Du Fu

[客至](http://www.literature.org.cn/Article.aspx?ID=6834)

```
舍南舍北皆春水，但见群鸥日日来。
花径不曾缘客扫，蓬门今始为君开。
盘飧市远无兼味，樽酒家贫只旧醅。
肯与邻翁相对饮？隔篱呼取尽余杯。
```

Here, the **good news** is the friend that, suddenly, shows up in the poet's gate, what's reason enough for a good night drinking with a few friends.

---

王维  Wang Wei

[杂诗](http://www.gushiwen.org/GuShiWen_e731c3242e.aspx?WebShieldDRSessionVerify=z40BXsaD0r3MjwalsN19)

```
君自故乡来，应知故乡事。
来日绮窗前，寒梅著花未？
```

杂诗

```
君自故乡来，应知故乡事。
来日绮窗前，寒梅着花未？
```

Here, the poet is happy because of the **good news** that a traveler might bring. It happens that this special traveler is coming from his home town.

Comment: You posted some of the poems twice. And it would be good if you added some statement about how each one relates to good news.

Comment: That's Traditional and Simplified Chinese. Yes, I'll add. Thank you.

Comment: The last poem is simplified both times. Thank you for adding the comments!

Answer (score 2):

烽火连三月，家书抵万金 －－ Good news in war.

Comment: A mail from home doesn't have to be good news...

Comment: May be. But receive a home letter from soldier at the frontier is a good news definitely.

Comment: Well... Sounds reasonable...

Answer (score 1):

The first allegory that comes into my mind is 塞翁失马，焉知非福。The allegory tells us that bad news sometimes becomes good, and vice versa.

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's not about "news". It means **things** that appear to be bad can turn out to be good later.

Comment: @bfrguci Not true. In Chinese "bad things" is the same as "bad news" in this allegory.

Answer (score 1):

- [xǐ dà pǔ bēn 喜大普奔](http://www.hanbridgemandarin.com/news/im-thrilled-to-death)
- huò rán kāi lǎnɡ 豁然开朗
- yòu jīnɡ yòu xǐ 又惊又喜
- dà xǐ ɡuò wànɡ 大喜过望
- xǐ cónɡ tiān jiànɡ 喜从天降

Comment: voted for `喜大普奔`

Answer (score 0):

静候佳音 (used at the end of mails): I look forward to your good news.